# Getting data from a document in FireBase and adding them into a map

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to transfer my data from `FireBase Collection` to a map. Then, the map data will go into `MultiSelectBottomSheetField`.

**Problems:** I am getting `"Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'"` instead of `'Home'` for example.

[image]

I still not getting the list of context from collection into `MultiSelectItem`

Also, I have noticed that when I start the app, the `MultiSelectionItem` is **empty**. It is displaying `"Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'"` when I display the main view a second time. I guess that a `SetState` is probably missing somewhere. But as I can not write set state in a constructor, I am puzzled.

This is driving me nuts as I do not find where the problem is coming from.
Many thanks for your help.

```
import 'package:flutter_swipe_action_cell/core/cell.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:multi_select_flutter/bottom_sheet/multi_select_bottom_sheet_field.dart';
import 'package:multi_select_flutter/util/multi_select_item.dart';

String inboxTaskDisplayed='';
int nbRecord=0;
var taskSelectedID;
var taskDone;

//------TEST
class ContextExisting {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  ContextExisting({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });
}

List<ContextExisting> _contexts = [];
List <ContextExisting>allMyContext=[];


TextEditingController passController = new TextEditingController();
//-----------------
var documentID;
var textController = TextEditingController();
var popUpTextController = TextEditingController();


//_-----------------
class Inbox_Test_For_Chip_Trial extends StatefulWidget {
  final String screenSelected;
  final String titlePage;
  Inbox_Test_For_Chip_Trial(Key key, {@required this.screenSelected, @required this.titlePage,}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _Inbox_Test_For_Chip_TrialState createState() => _Inbox_Test_For_Chip_TrialState(screenSelected, titlePage);
}

class _Inbox_Test_For_Chip_TrialState extends State<Inbox_Test_For_Chip_Trial> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _inboxFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String screenSelected;
  String titlePage;

  _Inbox_Test_For_Chip_TrialState(this.screenSelected,  this.titlePage,);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(titlePage + ' ('+nbRecord.toString()+')'),
    actions: <Widget>[

    ],
    ),

    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        height: 250,
        child: Column(
          //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            //FOR CONTEXT
            Flexible(child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
          .collection('contexts')
          .snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                        }
                    else {

                      var docs = snapshot.data.docs;
print('docs');
                      print (docs[2].id);

                      print(snapshot.data.docs.length);

                      int nbContext = snapshot.data.docs.length;

                      for (int i=0;i<nbContext; i++) {

                        _contexts.addAll([ContextExisting (id:i, name:snapshot.data.toString())]);
                        print(_contexts);
                      }

                return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .78,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                return Wrap(
                children: [Card(
                child: SwipeActionCell(
                key: ObjectKey(document['context_Name']),
                trailingActions: <SwipeAction>[

          ],

          child: ListTile(
          trailing: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
          onPressed: () async {
          taskSelectedID = FirebaseFirestore
                .instance
                .collection('Users')
                .doc(
          FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser
                .uid)
                .collection('contexts')
                .doc(document.id).toString();
        }
    ),

    leading: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
    minWidth: 30,
    minHeight: 35,
    maxWidth: 30,
    maxHeight: 35,
    ),

     //InkWell(child: Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
    ),
    title: Text(
    document['context_Name'],
    maxLines: 2,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    ),
    ),
    ),
    ),
    ]
    );
    }).toList(),
    ),
    );
    }
    }),),

            Column(children:[

              TestWidgetContext(),

            ]), //MyHomePage())
          ],
        ),
      ),
      //bottomNavigationBar:  MyBottomAppBar(),  //PersistentBottomNavBar(),
    );
  }
```

```
class TestWidgetContext extends StatefulWidget {

  TestWidgetContext({Key key})  : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestWidgetContextState createState() => _TestWidgetContextState();
}

class _TestWidgetContextState extends State<TestWidgetContext> {
  List itemsContext;
  List<ContextExisting> _selectedContext5 = [];

  final _itemsContext = _contexts
      .map((context) => MultiSelectItem<ContextExisting>(context, context.name))
      .toList();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _selectedContext5 = _contexts;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      children: [
        MultiSelectBottomSheetField(
          buttonText: Text("Contexts"),
          onConfirm: (val2) {
            
          },

          items: _itemsContext,
         // initialValue:
         // _itemsContext,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the error that you are receiving too

Comment: This is one problem: `List <allMyContext> =` use this instead `List allMyContext =`

Comment: @LaurentThomas Are you able to get the data from Firestore collection? Is your problem related to not having those data appear in MultiSelectionItem UI?

Comment: now, I have find the solution. I am getting the right data displayed on my widget.

Answer (score 1):

Since the code has a lot of errors, I am writing down my findings.

1. allMyContext is a list and if you wish to add elements to it you should be wring it as

`allMyContext.add(ContextExisting (id:i, name:doc.name));`

instead of `List<allMyContext> = ContextExisting (id:i, name:doc.name)`

Insde the on pressed

```
  taskSelectedID = (document.id).toString();
```

since you already have taken a document you don't have to query it again

```
final doc = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('contexts').get();
```

and

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).collection('contexts').snapshots(),
```

These two are contradictory. Is contexts a collection or a document?

Comment: Many thanks. Context is a collection

Comment: Try making these edits and update the results please

Comment: I have modified the code and I am getting less errors. But it is not working properly yet.

Comment: You added a  _Contexts with an upper case C change to _contexts. Please update the latest errors too

Comment: I have also updated the errors. I now have only 4 errors left.

Errors

Undefined name 'doc'.
The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ContextExisting'.
Instance member 'name' can't be accessed using static access.
The name 'context' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

```
child: Column(
          //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            //FOR CONTEXT
            Flexible(child: StreamBuilder(
            stream:  FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Users')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
            .collection('contexts')
            .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

              if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something went wrong');
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              // if connectionState is waiting
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                  {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  } else {

                for (int i=0;i<snapshot.data.docs.length;i++){
                 DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                _contexts.add(snap['context_Name']);
                }
                }
              }

              // return widgets and use data
              return Column(children:[

                TestWidgetContext(),

              ]); //MyHomePage())
```